# Divide and conquer algo. not giving proper output

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I tried to print the left and right parts of an array using *divide and conquer* algorithm but it is not giving output as required.

The code is given below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *arr, int l, int mid, int r) {
    cout << "Left Part: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < mid + 1; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    // cout << "\n";

    //print right part
    cout << "Right Part: ";
    for (int i = mid + 1; i < r + 1; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    // cout << "\n";
}

void divide(int *arr, int l, int r) {
    int mid;
    if (l < r) {
        mid = (l + (r - l)) / 2;

        divide(arr, l, mid);
        divide(arr, mid + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10 };
    divide(arr, 0, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Left Part: 38 Right Part: 27
```

Not printing printing full array

Comment: What do you think `mid=(l+(r-l))/2;` does?

Comment: Try with mid = l + (r - l) / 2. Also, This won't print the array once. Rather you will have elements getting print multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you compute the `mid` index is incorrect: instead of `mid = (l + (r - l)) / 2;` you should write:

```
mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
```

Note also these remarks:

- the first printing loop should start at `i = l`, not `i = 0`.
- you should print the newlines to produce readable output.

In your implementation, `r` is the index of the last element of the right part and `mid` is the index of the last element of the left part. This is somewhat confusing.  It is idiomatic in C and C++ to select `mid` as the index of the first item in the right part and `r` the index past the last element of the right part. This allow the first call to use the length of the array and avoids confusing and error prone +1/-1 adjustments.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *arr, int start, int mid, int end) {
    cout << "Left Part:";
    for (int i = start; i < mid; i++) {
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";

    //print right part
    cout << "Right Part:";
    for (int i = mid; i < end; i++) {
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void divide(int *arr, int start, int end) {
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        divide(arr, start, mid);
        divide(arr, mid, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10 };
    divide(arr, 0, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    return 0;
}
```